# Is $D = \{(x,y) \in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2y=1\}$ a closed set or open set?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

> Is $D = \{(x,y) \in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2y=1\}$ an open or closed set?

Correct me if I'm wrong, an open set is a set that doesn't contain all its limits. From graphing $y = 1/x^2$ I can see that the curves converge towards the $x$- and $y$-axis but never touch the axes.

Therefore, the set $D$ is an open set.

Thats my intuition but I don't know how to formally prove it.

Comment: What can we say about any neighborhood of any point on the curve?

Comment: What does your purported argument have to do with a set being open?

Comment: An open set can contain all it's limits. Examples are the whole $\overline{\mathbb R^2}$ and $\varnothing$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first place, it's a closed set. If $((x_n,y_n))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a sequence of points of $D$ which converges to some $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2$, then\begin{align}x^2y&=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n^{\,2}y_n\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}1\\&=1,\end{align}and therefore $(x,y)\in D$.

In the second place, even if it was not closed, you would not be able to deduce from that that $D$ is open. Sets are not doors: they can be both and open and they can also be not closed nor open.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

$D$ is the inverse image under the continuous map $f : (x,y) \mapsto x^2y$ of the closed singleton $\{1\}$. Hence $D$ is closed.